# SharePoint 2010 - Three-State ootb Workflow with multiple user for a step?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I want to use the three state out of the box workflow in SharePoint 2010.
My problem is now, that I only can assign a task to one user for a step (It is not possible to add a second person in this field)

Is there any way to assign a task to a group? Like a exchange group or something else?

Comment: Please ask your question here : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that multiple users are not allowed for the field. But you can assign the respective task to an Active Directory group. If you would want more customization you would need to implement the workflow yourself.